# Angular router.url - passing id

Tags: angular, navigation, router

In my template I have this navigation that checks the ngIf router.url is = to current url, I want to display those other links in my nav.

The thing is I dont how if it is possible to do this in the way I am trying to do. How can I correctly write the syntax so that I can get this dynamic id in the template. I tried many ways :

```
                     like so -   '/csgo/match/${id}'
                                 '/csgo/match/id'  
                                 '/csgo/match/:id'

<ng-template [ngIf]="router.url === '/csgo/match/${id}'">
<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="csgo/results">Results</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="csgo/ranking">World Ranking</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="csgo/upcoming">Upcoming</a>
</ng-template>
```

Routing module

```
  { path: '', component: HomeRouterComponent },
  { path: 'csgo', component: CsgoComponent},
  { path: 'csgo/results', component: CsResultsComponent},
  { path: 'csgo/ranking', component: RankingComponent},
  { path: 'csgo/match/:id', component:MatchComponent},
  { path: 'csgo/team/:id', component: TeamPageComponent},
  { path: 'csgo/upcoming', component:UpcomingLiveComponent},
```

Comment: ${id) is not correct syntax. It should be ${id} <- look at the closing bracket

Comment: i just did typo mistake by giving this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ng-template *ngIf="showRoutes">
<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="csgo/results">Results</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="csgo/ranking">World Ranking</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="csgo/upcoming">Upcoming</a>
</ng-template>
```

in your `.ts` ,

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private _route : ActivatedRoute){}
```

Subscribe to your route params :

```
this._route.paramMap.subscribe((params)=>{
 //change the value of showRoutes based on your requirements
});
```

Comment: `this._route.paramMap.subscribe((params)=>{
 //change the value of showRoutes based on your requirements
}); ` so should i make a method for this? and give a boolean for showRoutes, could you maybe provide a full example of this? not sure how this params working

Comment: @Dovydas you can subscribe to it during the initialisation of your component where the routes(nav bar) are defined . maybe inside ``ngOnInit()``

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params)=>{
    this.showRoutes = '/csgo/match/' +params['id'];
    });
  }`

Comment: however it doesnt matter what i type inside the string `this.showRoutes = ' '` or leaving just empty result is the same, and the nav then shows globally on all other links, not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Dovydas ``this.showRoutes = false`` will hide your ``ng-template``

Comment: yes, but then i doesnt show on the `csgo/match` aswel. If `this.showRoutes = true` it shows globally on all `csgo/` path i just want to show it on `csgo/match`

Comment: @Dovydas if your params['id'] == undefined then you can change ``this.showRoutes = true`` else ``this.showRoutes=false``.

Answer (score 0):

Your template *ngIf condition should be like below:
${id} should be after quotation.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="router.url === '/csgo/match/'${id)">
```

Comment: then my page is completly broke - have error Template parse errors:
`Parser Error: Unexpected token '$' at column 30 in [router.url === '/csgo/match/'${id)] in ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.html@67:29 ("
                </ng-template>`

Answer (score 0):

`[ngIf]="router.url === '/csgo/match/' +id"`

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at column 31 in expression [router.url === '/csgo/match/+id] at column 32 in [router.url === '/csgo/match/+id] in ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.html@67:29 ("
                </ng-template>`

Comment: `id` should be defined in your component

Comment: i missed the  single quote '   `'/csgo/match/+id` at the and it, so i tried `'/csgo/match/'+id` no i have no errors, but doesn't show anything in nav aswel

Comment: not sure then, may be try `[ngIf]="router.url === '/csgo/match/' +{{id}}"`

Comment: `+{{id}}` that one breaks the template, that first option `+id` it doesn't brake anything, but as i said not showing any links in the nav

Comment: are you sure `id` contains something?, and `router.url` also has some value?